# jQuery AJAX Post not posting data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Right I have given in, after about 2 hours trying to figure out this issue I've caved, help me out stackoverflow!

Trying to post a product id along with quantity to a php file that will return errors if it finds any

jQuery code -

```
$('span.add_to_cart').click(function () {
        $('div.cart').append('<span class="loading">LOADING</span>');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/onlineshop/scripts/add_to_cart.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { prod_id: $('input.product_id').val(), 
                    quantity: $('input.quantity').val()
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('span.loading').remove();
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError, data) {
                alert("Error: " + thrownError);
                $('span.loading').remove();
            }
        })
    });
```

And my PHP page is just trying to `print_r($_POST)`

It seems that it is not posting my data, I've tried many many different things, all give me the error saying that there is no data being posted.

Comment: Have you tried posting just sample data instead of evaluating an expression? Would at least help narrow down the culprit. ;-)

Comment: When you are using POST  you should use some HTTP headers,  contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" . If you do not provide this header, your data will not be send. Try adding it after the verb POST.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try changing the `contentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or just dropping it since it is the default value.

Comment: Bingo! I see the answer I've been looking for! Thanks a bunch, having spent 2 hours just going, what the heck is wrong here it's kind of annoying to find it was just that. Oh well! Will learn in the future!

Comment: this worked perfect for me as well... I was using `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"` so changing it to `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` brought my app to life, thanks for sharing this useful info

Comment: This fixed it for me also after wondering why the heck my form data wasn't sending for hours. Dropping it didn't work. I had to explicity add `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I really wish I knew why this was necessary.

Comment: One more thing, if you want the charset to be utf-8 you can do `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @JasonDavis @Gavin , May I know the difference between `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json;charset=utf-8`? and what scenario we can use these?

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that the data you are posting is not matching the `content-type` you are sending.

`contentType` is for the data being sent to the server, and `dataType` is for the data being received from the server.

Just remove the `contentType: "application/json"` from your code.